# send a message while redirecting

Tags: node.js, express

hello please I want to send a message while redirecting but I got an error

```
let message = "An error ocoured while updating user record to ahow verified."
res.redirect(`/verified/error=true&message=${message}`)
```

this is the route

```
app.get("/verified", (req, res) => {
  res.render("auth-verified-email");
})
```

error

> Cannot GET /verified/error=true&message=Link%20has%20expired%20.Please%20sign%20up%20again

Comment: Did you mean ``res.redirect(`/verified?error=true&message=${message}`)`` (question mark instead of slash)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
app.get("/verified/:params", (req, res) => {
  res.render("auth-verified-email");
})
```